# JSON fields returning null when containing html tags

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to expose some data in a table that contains HTML tags, when I access the page all of the fields not containing HTML are fine but any containing html return null.

I have tried setting the fields to VarChar and Text but neither seem to work. The table is also set to `utf8_general_ci`.

*request_step_content.php*

```
<?php
header("Content-Type:application/json");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$user = "userName";
$pass = "userPassword";
$table = "myTable";

$db=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$table", $user, $pass);

$query = "SELECT * FROM steps";

try {
    $stmt = $db->query($query);
    }
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error.";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

if($rows) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Step";
    $response["step"] = array();

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $post = array();
        $post["id"] = $row["intID"];
        $post["heading"] = $row["strStepheading"];
        $post["keyPrinciple"] = $row["strKeyPrinciple"];
        $post["pillar"] = $row["strPillar"];
        $post["introduction"] = $row["memIntroduction"];
        $post["actionSteps"] = $row["memActionSteps"];
        $post["actionPoints"] = $row["memActionPoints"];
        $post["studyAndUnderstanding"] = $row["memStudyUnderstanding"];

        array_push($response["step"], $post);
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
}
else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No Steps Available";
    die(json_encode($response));
}
?>
```

*json response*

```
{"success":1,
 "message":
           "Step",
           "step":[{"id":"1",
                          "heading":"Test Heading",
                          "keyPrinciple":"Key Principle: Test Key Principle",
                          "pillar":"Pillar 1: Pillar",
                          "introduction":null,
                          "actionSteps":null,
                          "actionPoints":null,
                          "studyAndUnderstanding":null}]}
```

Comment: use htmlentities function http://php.net/manual/fr/function.htmlentities.php on $row who contains html, you can complete with options on json_encode see options part detail of http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: I implemented the html entities and it has changed the fields from null to empty. I'm not 100% on what I am supposed to do with the json_encode options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue with some help of @Fky's answer regarding encoding.

Using `utf_encode()` I now have all fields including the html content in my JSON fields. Here's the edited code:

```
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $post = array();
        $post["id"] = $row["intID"];
        $post["heading"] = $row["strStepheading"];
        $post["keyPrinciple"] = $row["strKeyPrinciple"];
        $post["pillar"] = $row["strPillar"];
        $post["introduction"] = utf8_encode($row["memIntroduction"]);
        $post["actionSteps"] = utf8_encode($row["memActionSteps"]);
        $post["actionPoints"] = utf8_encode($row["memActionPoints"]);
        $post["studyAndUnderstanding"] = utf8_encode($row["memStudyUnderstanding"]);
```

Thank you for the help all.

Comment: Good to know :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem will be in encoding. Columns in DB tables can be UTF-8 but stored data doesnt have to be in UTF-8. PHP function json_encode accepts only UTF-8 data. Check your stored DB data.

Comment: Thank you! you put me onto the answer, wrapped the array elements in `utf_encode($string)` and it all works now!